# Azure AD users sync with Custom User Management using SOAP

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I would like to synchronise Azure AD users with my custom home grown user management solution using SOAP API's. My custom home grown user management has SOAP API's for all the user management operations. Any suggestions or pointers for synchronising AD users to my custom home grown user management solution using REST API's is useful.

thanks Lokesh

Answer (score 1):

There is an open standard I can think of, called [SCIM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_for_Cross-domain_Identity_Management).

This is taken from the microsoft docs that describes using SCIM with Azure AD

> As an application developer, you can use the System for Cross-Domain Identity Management (SCIM) user management API to enable automatic provisioning of users and groups between your application and Azure AD. This article describes how to build a SCIM endpoint and integrate with the Azure AD provisioning service. The SCIM specification provides a common user schema for provisioning. When used in conjunction with federation standards like SAML or OpenID Connect, SCIM gives administrators an end-to-end, standards-based solution for access management.

([source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/app-provisioning/use-scim-to-provision-users-and-groups))

Basically you have to implement some well defined endpoints and Azure AD will take care of the syncing.